# Find a Document based on a Reference To the Parent In the Child

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

There are  2 collections **Movie** and **Rank Movie** .This 2 collections having **referenced relationship** .

**`Movie model`**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    m_tmdb_id: {
        type: Number,
        unique: true,
        index: true
    },
    m_adult: {
        type: Boolean
    },
    m_backdrop_path: {
        type: String,
    },
    m_title: {
        type: Number
    },
    m_genres: {
        type: Array
    }

});
var MovieModel = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema);
module.exports = {
    movie: MovieModel
}
```

**`Rank movie model`**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var rankMovieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    movie: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Movie',
        unique: true
    },
    rank: {
        type: Number
    },
    count: {
        type: Number
    }
});
var RankMovieModel = mongoose.model('RankMovie', rankMovieSchema);
module.exports = {
    rankmovie: RankMovieModel
}
```

I need to  select all the items from the collection rank movie having  a particular  title[Condition on movie collection ].How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the "best" way to do this is rather using [`.aggregate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) and [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to "join" the data and "filter" on the match conditions. This is very effective since MongoDB actually performs all of this on the "server" itself, as compared to issuing "multiple" queries as [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) does.

```
MovieModel.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "m_title": m_title } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": RankMovieModel.collection.name,
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "movie",
    "as": "rankings"
  }}
])
```

> **Note:** The `RankMovieModel.collection.name` is a nice way of getting the "underlying" collection name from the `Model` registered with Mongoose. Since the operation is on the "server", MongoDB needs the "real collection name", so we can either "hardcode" that or just get it from the information registered on the Model itself. As is done here.

If there are "lots" of rankings, then you are best to use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), which will create a document for each related "rankings" item:

```
MovieModel.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "m_title": m_title } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": RankMovieModel.collection.name,
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "movie",
    "as": "rankings"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$rankings" }
])
```

There is also a special handling here of how MongoDB deals with "joining" documents to avoid breaching the 16MB BSON limit. So in fact this special thing happens when [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) directly follows a [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) pipeline stage:

```
    {
        "$lookup" : {
            "from" : "rankmovies",
            "as" : "rankings",
            "localField" : "_id",
            "foreignField" : "movie",
            "unwinding" : {
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : false
            }
        }
    }
```

So the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) actually "disappears" and instead is "rolled-up" into the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) itself as if this were "one" operation. That way we do not create an "array" directly within the parent document which would cause the size to exceed 16MB in extreme cases with many "related" items.

---

If you do not have a MongoDB that supports [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) ( *MongoDB 3.2 minunum* ) then you could use a "virtual" with [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) instead (*requires Mongoose 4.5.0 minimum*). But note this actually performs **"two"** queries to the server:

First add the "virtual" to the schema:

```
movieSchema.virtual("rankings",{
  "ref": "Movie",
  "localField": "_id",
  "foreignField": "movie"
});
```

Then issue the query with [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html):

```
MovieModel.find({ "m_title": m_title })
  .populate('rankings')
  .exec()
```

Comment: Thanks fro your help.My requirement is little bit different.Updated the question.

Comment: @Muhsin That's highly rude. The question is completely different. You should revert back to your original question and [Ask a new Question instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Changing your question like that is not the polite way to behave here. You have an answer to the question you actually asked. Anything else is a **new question**. Happy to look at new questions, as long as this one remains unchanged.

Comment: @Muhsin Thankyou, that's better. A tip for your future posts. Do not "obscure" the `ObjectId` values. Particularly when you are providing data related to a "join". Once you do that it makes the values 'invalid" and people cannot simply "copy" the data and use to test possible solutions that would give you an answer. So make sure when you ask questions on that subject to use values which can be applied with a simple "copy/paste" operation so people can actually use it.