# Find documents based on a Reference to the Parent in the Child with Pagination

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

There are  2 collections **Movie** and **Rank Movie** .This 2 collections having **referenced relationship** .

**`Movie model`**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    m_tmdb_id: {
        type: Number,
        unique: true,
        index: true
    },
    m_adult: {
        type: Boolean
    },
    m_backdrop_path: {
        type: String,
    },
    m_title: {
        type: Number
    },
    m_genres: {
        type: Array
    }

});
var MovieModel = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema);
module.exports = {
    movie: MovieModel
}
```

**`Rank movie model`**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var rankMovieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    movie: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Movie',
        unique: true
    },
    rank: {
        type: Number
    },
    count: {
        type: Number
    }
});
var RankMovieModel = mongoose.model('RankMovie', rankMovieSchema);
module.exports = {
    rankmovie: RankMovieModel
}
```

I need to select all the top 10 items in each query [Pagination] from the collection rank movie having a particular `m_genres` name[Condition on movie collection ].

Ex:

**Movie collection**

```
[{
    "_id": ObjectId("5930ea4806fb9e365e0d55b5"),
    "m_tmdb_id": 888724,
    "m_imdb_id": "sd2806",
    "m_title": "Mechanic: Resurrection",
    "m_genres": [{
        "name": "Action",
        "id": 28
    }, {
        "name": "Crime",
        "id": 80
    }, {
        "name": "Thriller",
        "id": 53
    }]
}, {
    "_id": ObjectId("583e3bd69e2ea90c69c5a254"),
    "m_tmdb_id": 23924,
    "m_imdb_id": "tt3d2806",
    "m_title": "Inter",
    "m_genres": [{
        "name": "Drama",
        "id": 32
    }, {
        "name": "Crime",
        "id": 80
    }]
}, {
    "_id": ObjectId("5930eaa706fb9e365e0d55c8"),
    "m_tmdb_id": 378924,
    "m_imdb_id": "sdstt3522806",
    "m_title": "Spiderman",
    "m_genres": [{
        "name": "Action",
        "id": 28
    }, {
        "name": "Crime",
        "id": 80
    }, {
        "name": "Thriller",
        "id": 53
    }]
}]
```

**Rank Movie Collection**

```
[{
    "_id": ObjectId("59398daaad49f32c20115422"),
    "movie": ObjectId("5930ea4806fb9e365e0d55b5"),
    "count": 5
}, {
    "_id": ObjectId("59397f7095f0b91ffbdeb1f8"),
    "movie": ObjectId("583e3bd69e2ea90c69c5a254"),
    "count": 1
}, {
    "_id": ObjectId("59397f6695f0b91ffbdeb1f6"),
    "movie": ObjectId("5930eaa706fb9e365e0d55c8"),
    "count": 5
}]
```

If i am giving `m_genres` names as Crime,Thriller.The query should fetch top 10 items from rank movie which having `m_genres` names Crime,Thriller.How can i achieve this?

**My JS Code**

```
RankMovie
    .find(queryOptions)
    .limit(10)
    .skip(1 * 10)
    .populate('movie', 'm_tmdb_id  m_title m_generes ')
    .sort('-count')
    .exec(function(err, movies) {
        if(err){
            return res.status(404).json(err);
        }
        return res.status(200).json(movies);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        return res.status(500).json(error);
    });
```

Comment: `ObectId` values have been "obscured". Please fix them.

Comment: @NeilLunn :Question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this "still" has the best method using `.aggregate()` with [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to join the data.

```
var wantedGenres = ["Action","Crime"];
var page = 1;

RankMovie.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Movie.collection.name,
    "localField": "movie",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "movie"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$movie" },
  { "$match": { "movie.m_genres.name": { "$in": wantedGenres }  }},
  { "$sort": { "count": -1 } },
  { "$project": {
    "movie": {
      "m_title": "$movie.m_title",
      "m_tmdb_id": "$movie.m_tmdb_id",
      "m_genres": "$movie.m_genres",
    },
    "count": 1
  }},
  { "$skip": 10*page },
  { "$limit": 10 },
])
```

This works out to be efficient since the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) get combined into the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) itself, and only return the items that actually matched the given criteria in the `$match` as opposed to "ALL" related data. This is explained in [the Answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44917963/2313887) in full.

But this is what happens to those three stages:

```
    {
        "$lookup" : {
            "from" : "movies",
            "as" : "movie",
            "localField" : "movie",
            "foreignField" : "_id",
            "unwinding" : {
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : false
            },
            "matching" : {
                "m_genres.name" : {
                    "$in" : [ 
                        "Action", 
                        "Crime"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Of course then we [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) in order to have the matching results in the correct and wanted order. Then it simply is a matter of selecting the wanted fields with [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) ( *note that [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) will not work here, since we want to "overwrite"* ) and performing the [`$skip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) and [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) for the pagination.

Trying to do this "client side" as `.populate()` does would be next to impossible and practically impossible in real situations. The problem of course being that the "selection by genres" needs to happen "before" you actually begin to "paginate".

So the only way that could possibly happen is with a "relatively small" list of "movies", because you would indeed need to make the selection on the "genres" first and then do the rest of the query.

The "totally impractical" way would look something like:

```
var wantedGenres = ["Action","Crime"];
var page = 1;

Movie.find({ "m_genres.name": { "$in": wantedGenres } })
  .select({ "_id": 1 })
  .exec()
  .then(movies =>
    RankMovie.find({ "movie": { "$in": movies.map(m => m._id) })
      .populate('movie', 'm_tmdb_id  m_title m_genres')
      .sort('-count')
      .skip(10*page)
      .limit(10)
      .exec()
  ).then(rankings => {
    // deal with response
  })
  .catch(err => res.status(500).json(err))
```

But of course that pulls "ALL" the matching `"movies"` over the wire to the client before issuing the query. And possibly breaks the BSON limit on request with the `$in` argument of `ids`.

The aggregate statement on the other hand, will not have the same limitation.

Comment: Thanks for you help.The first approach returning all the values from the movie document

Comment: @Muhsin You need the `$addFields` in there and it must be addressing the same name as what was used in the output from `$lookup`. This "overwrites" the full details with just the wanted fields. This is "by design". It is not presently possible to "restrict" the returned fields from a `$lookup` operation. So you need the stages **exactly** as presented here.

Comment: @Muhsin Actually I see it now. Unfortunately `$addFields` will not do. I was presuming the "nested" syntax would actually overwrite. It does not. Instead we need to `$project` and name all the fields. Let me correct.

Comment: Okay.Let me check